# text to md5 converter script in asp.net

Tags: text, md5

I have a website in asp.net 2.0, As I need to use CCNOW payment integration to make a payment but for this I'll have to send request to CCNOW in MD5 format but I can't able to generate my values to CCNOW MD5 format. So, could you please any one have a script/function that will convert given string into MD5?

Answer (score 0):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) isn't a "format," is a hashing algorithm. Use [the `MD5` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx). Assuming you're using C#, it would look something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx#aaeba7a2-f5ea-48b5-8f8b-8e6f431de84a):

```
static string getMd5Hash(string input)
{
    // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
    MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
    // and create a string.
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    // Return the hexadecimal string.
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetMD5(string value) {
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    byte[] md5Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
    byte[] cryString = md5.ComputeHash(md5Bytes);
    string md5Str = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < cryString.Length; i++) {
        md5Str += cryString[i].ToString("X");
    }
    return md5Str;
}
```

Call it with:

```
GetMD5(stringToConvert);
```